# How to write a pygalmesh mesh object into a binary STL file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, 3d, cgal

After generating a 3D mesh with

```
import pygalmesh

s = pygalmesh.Ball([0, 0, 0], 1.0)
mesh = pygalmesh.generate_mesh(s, cell_size=0.2)
```

I would like to write it into a binary STL file. For .off format there is a perfect small solution:

```
import meshio
# this would be an off file format file:
meshio.write("out.off", mesh)
```

Bust replacing "out.off" by "out.stl" produces an error:

```
File "C:\bin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\meshio\stl\_stl.py", 
line 161, in write keys = set(mesh.cells.keys())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```